# Why does Excel get another result than PowerShell and Google when trying to find out how many days have passed since 01.01.1900?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

A colleague told me: "Excactly 43871 days have passed since 01.01.1900". 
Today is 10.02.2020.

I wanted to check that with PowerShell, but I got another result:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-TimeSpan ([datetime]"01.01.1900") (Get-Date)


Days              : 43869
Hours             : 11
Minutes           : 15
Seconds           : 46
Milliseconds      : 304
```

So I was confused because there was a 2 days difference. So I asked Google the almighty:

[image: GoogleDaysPassedSearch]

As you can see, Google also says 43869 days have passed, not 43871.

So I asked my friend how he calculated it. He did it in Excel, by formatting a cell to `dateonly`. When he then writes an `int` in it, Excel will cast it to a date, e.g

- `15641` becomes `27.10.1942`
- `19874` becomes `30.05.1954`
- `43869` becomes `08.02.2020` (?)
- `43871` becomes `10.02.2020` (?)

Is Excel living 2 days ahead of us or why does it think there were 2 more days than there actually were since 01.01.1900? Is it missing something?

Here's a little gif of it (unfortunately in German since I have a German Excel):

[image: ExcelCalculationGif]

Comment: Enable 1904 date calculations in excel, and the date since 01.01.1904 will now match up,

Comment: @SQLTemp I'm more interested in the "why", not a possible solution

Comment: there's no need to convert dates to integers. Just subtract 2 cell containing dates directly and you'll get the differences between them. For example A1 = 27.10.1942, B1 = 30.05.1954, C1 = B1 - A1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The why:**

First of all, your friend and Google are calculating differently.
Excel (using the 1900 Date system) only thinks there is one extra day since 1900.

Excel stores dates as serial numbers where `1-Jan-1900` = `1`
And `10-Feb-2020` --> `43871`

So **days since** by Excel should be `43871` - `1` --> `43870`

However, the Excel calculation is incorrect.

When Excel was introduced, Lotus123 was the leading spreadsheet program.

Lotus 123 had a bug wherein it thought the year 1900 was a leap year.

For compatibility in view of the competition, Excel included that bug. However, since `29-Feb-1900` is a non-existent date, other methods will show, properly, `43869` when subtracting the two dates.

By the way, Excel VBA also calculates the date difference correctly --> `43869`

Comment: Is there a reason, why this never got fixed?

Comment: @SimonS how can you fix it without breaking older software and spreadsheets? Other people will complain if they see dates being different when opening with a newer Excel version

Comment: @phuclv You can then explain them, that they finally see a correct date :-). I think there should at least be an option to use a correct 1900 System, so that I don't have to worry if my calculated dates are correct or not.

Comment: @SimonS no, that's not a correct date. When a user saved 11/1/1980 just to see 10/1/1980 when reopening it then it's a bug, not a correct date. And there was already an option, which is the 1904 date system. It's already explained in Excel documentation

Comment: @SimonS Supposedly, that decision was made because it would have been too difficult to make the "fix" backward compatible. The only real issue is the one you have come across, where counting the days difference for a date range that spans the non-existent `29-Feb-1900` will be off by one

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Excel supports two different date systems. These systems are the 1900 date system and the 1904 date system

**The 1900 Date System**

In the 1900 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1900. When you enter a date, the date is converted into a serial number that represents the number of elapsed days starting with 1 for January 1, 1900. For example, if you enter July 5, 1998, Excel converts the date to the serial number 35981.
By default, Microsoft Excel for Windows uses the 1900 date system. The 1900 date system enables better compatibility between Excel and other spreadsheet programs, such as Lotus 1-2-3, that are designed to run under MS-DOS or Microsoft Windows.

**The 1904 Date System**

In the 1904 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1904. When you enter a date, the date is converted into a serial number that represents the number of elapsed days since January 1, 1904, starting with 0 for January 1, 1904. For example, if you enter July 5, 1998, Excel converts the date to the serial number 34519.
Because of the design of early Macintosh computers, dates before January 1, 1904, were not supported. This design was intended to prevent problems related to the fact that 1900 was not a leap year. In the past, Excel for Macintosh defaulted to using the 1904 date system for workbooks originating on a Macintosh. However, Excel for Macintosh now defaults to the 1900 date system and supports dates as early as January 1, 1900.

**The Difference Between the Date Systems**

Because the two date systems use different starting days, the same date is represented by different serial numbers in each date system. For example, July 5, 1998 can have two different serial numbers, as follows.

```
Date system          Serial number of July 5, 1998
1900 date system     35981
1904 date system     34519
```

**Source:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system